# iOS: SWRevealViewController revealToggle is been call but doesn't do nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard

I'm trying to implement SWRevealViewController on this scenario:

[image]
From my main viewController:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SWRevealViewController *SWR = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:SWR animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

From my green view controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    self.reveal = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] init];
    self.reveal.delegate = self;
    self.menu.target = self;
    self.menu.action = @selector(revealToggleAction:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.reveal.panGestureRecognizer];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
}

-(void)revealToggleAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.reveal revealToggle:self];
}
```

The revealToggle action is been call but doesn't do anything. It doesn't load the rear view controller. Any of you knows this happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are showing the side bar menu from right side.

First Embed your first view controller to navigation controller, then in your first view controller `viewdidload()` or `viewDidAppear` method add below mentioned code i.e.

```
//this is your side menu view controller.

UIViewController *sideMenuController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourSideMenuIdentifier"];

//this is the navigation controller embed to your green view controller.

UINavigationController *nc1 =
(UINavigationController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourNavigationControllerIdentifier"];

//This is your reveal view Controller.

SWRevealViewController *revealViewController =
[[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRightViewController:sideMenuController frontViewController:nc1];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:revealViewController animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

This will navigate to Controller i.e Green View Controller.

then in your green view controller `viewdidload()` or `viewDidAppear` method add below mentioned code i.e.

```
//GreenViewController.h file

@interface GreenViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sideBarItem;
@end


//Your GreenViewController.m file

_sideBarItem.target = self.revealViewController;
_sideBarItem.action = @selector(rightRevealToggle:);
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Note: For more details, check below mentioned link

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 1):

You need set SWRevealViewController is the initial view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of SWRevealViewController.

I think if you set the `self.reveal` to `self.revealViewController` it will work.